# Device responsive css

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, html, css

This might look similar to most of the other questions but cant seem to find this exact solution??

I wanna have a web design thats responsive on the Device-max-width so that when a normal browser user minimize he's webpage it just gonna be the regular website, but when you enter from a phone your gonna see the mobile website (but its still done with css) atm i have this:

```
<link href="<%= AutoVersioning.VersionizePath("/css/all.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media='screen and (min-width: 480px)' />
<link href='/css/mobile.css' rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" media='screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px)' />
```

This is the easy way to do it here it asks for browser width and not the device width..

So summed up how do i ask for the device width and how do i use that to choose css sheet?

**EDIT***

I found out i wanna ask on if the device is a mobile and if yes then use another stylesheet cause it seems that alot of phones now have alot above 480px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a specific stylesheet for mobile devices without regard to screen size, the I would recommend to check the user agent on the server side and only output the link tag for the mobile CSS if it is determined to be a mobile browser making the request for the page.

Here is the function I usually use to check if the request is coming from a mobile browser.

```
    public static bool MobileBrowserDetected()
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;

        var userAgent = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];

        if (userAgent != null)
        {
            userAgent = userAgent.ToLower();
        }

        // Checks the user-agent
        if (userAgent != null)
        {
            // Checks if its a Windows browser but not a Windows Mobile browser
            if (userAgent.Contains("windows") && !userAgent.Contains("windows ce") && !userAgent.Contains("iemobile"))
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Checks if it is a mobile browser
            const string pattern = "up.browser|up.link|windows ce|iphone|iemobile|mini|mmp|symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp|android";
            var mc = Regex.Matches(userAgent, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (mc.Count > 0)
                return true;

            // Checks if the 4 first chars of the user-agent match any of the most popular user-agents
            const string popularUserAgent = "|acs-|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-|dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-|maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv|palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany|sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo|teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3c |wap-|wapa|wapi|wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-|";
            if (popularUserAgent.Contains("|" + userAgent.Substring(0, 4) + "|"))
                return true;
        }

        // Checks the accept header for wap.wml or wap.xhtml support
        var accept = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT"];
        if (accept != null)
        {
            if (accept.Contains("text/vnd.wap.wml") || accept.Contains("application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml"))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        // Checks if it has any mobile HTTP headers

        var xWapProfile = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE"];
        var profile = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_PROFILE"];
        var opera = context.Request.Headers["HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA"];

        return xWapProfile != null || profile != null || opera != null;
    }
```

Comment: I just edited my answer to include a function I use to check if the user agent represents a mobile device

Answer (score 3):

You could try this

```
<link href  ="all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href  ="/css/mobile.css" rel='stylesheet'
      media ='screen and (max-device-width: 480px)' />
```

Load `all.css` with common rule for both desktop and mobile, then revert previous rules or add new rules on `mobile.css` checking for `max-device-width`

See jsbin example: http://jsbin.com/emafuk/1/edit
Even if you resize a desktop browser, the rule defined with max-device-width is not applied

Comment: Sorry was abit fast their refresh the question